# AutoHotKey: Instant text replace

Tags: text, replace, autohotkey, instant

One part of my AutoHotKey script replaces `@@` with my email address. Currently, I'm doing this like so:

```
::@@::
SendInput, example@domain.com
return
```

Simple enough and it works fairly well but you need to push space / comma / period / etc before it is replaced. Is there a way instantly replace it without any further interaction - it's replace as soon as the criteria is matched?

Following [the AutoHotKey documentation](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StringReplace.htm), I've tried:

```
StringReplace, var_Email, var_Email, @@, example@domain.com, All
```

but it just clears the `@@`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are looking for the * option in your hotstring. This option replaces the string as soon as it is detected without an extra key.

```
:*:@@::example@domain.com
```

will achieve what you are looking for.

The documentation for the Options are located here: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm